# EXIT_FAILURE en c

Tags: c

quería saber que es lo que hace `EXIT_FAILURE`. Sé que es un código del paquete `<stdlib.h>`, me refiero que tienes un método int y pones `return 0;` o `return EXIT_FAILURE;`

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, revisa por favor [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio y obtengas la ayuda requerida, saludos.

Comment: `EXIT_FAILURE` lo que hace, es indicar que una función terminó con alguna falla. Lo opuesto a esa macro sería `EXIT_SUCCESS`, indica que la función terminó con éxito (sin ningún error).

Answer (score 1):

En entornos de consola suele ser bastante común ejecutar scripts (batch, sh, ...). Estos scripts suelen, a su vez, ejecutar programas... y necesitan un mecanismo que permita comprobar si dichos programas han finalizado correctamente o no.

Una vía para hacer esto podría pasar por redirigir la salida del programa para poder analizarla, pero esta solución es bastante compleja y propensa a errores.

Otra vía, mucho más común y estandarizada, pasa por analizar un entero devuelto por el programa a la finalización del mismo. Este valor, por norma general, suele ser:

- 0: El programa ha finalizado correctamente
- otro valor: El programa ha finalizado con error y el código devuelto debería permitir identificar el error.

Pues bien, en C existen dos macros con los valores básicos para esta salida:

- `EXIT_SUCCESS`: El valor de esta macro es típicamente 0, es decir, puesto en el return del `main` vendría a indicar que el programa ha finalizado correctamente
- `EXIT_FAILURE`: Este valor de esta macro suele ser -1. Se puede utilizar para indicar que el programa ha encontrado un error indeterminado.

No son más que convenciones que utilizan diferentes programas para facilitar un poco  la vida al resto y su utilidad queda reducida a lo comentado en esta respuesta.

Como nota final, remarcar que no son más que macros y que su uso no es para nada obligatorio. Sin embargo, recurrir a ellas mejora la legibilidad del código y expresa cierta intencionalidad, lo cual ayuda a que el código sea menos propenso a errores.